# The dimension of the weak star closed subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $M$ be a subspace of the  topological dual space $X^{*}$ (where $X$ is an infinite dimensional complex Banach space), we denote by $\sigma(X^{*}, X)$ the weak star topology of $X^{*},$ by $\overline M^{\sigma(X^{*}, X)}$ the weak star closure of $M$ and by $\overline{M}$ the closure of $M$ in the natural  topology  of $X^{*}$.

What is the relation between  $\mbox{dim}\,\frac{X^{*}}{\overline M^{\sigma(X^{*}, X)}}$  and $\mbox{dim}\,\frac{X^{*}}{\overline{M}}$ and $\mbox{dim}\,\frac{X^{*}}{M}$?

Comment: Each time you say "closed", do you mean "closure"?

Comment: Yes thank you Plop

Comment: Do you know that $M \subset \overline{M} \subset \overline{M}^{\sigma(X^*,X)}$, so that the dimensions of the quotients are ordered in the opposite direction?

Comment: Yes i know, but  i ask, does   $\mbox{dim}\,\frac{X^{*}}{\overline M^{\sigma(X^{*}, X)}}<\infty$  imply  that $\mbox{dim}\,\frac{X^{*}}{\overline M^{\sigma(X^{*}, X)}}=\mbox{dim}\,\frac{X^{*}}{\overline{M}}=\mbox{dim}\,\frac{X^{*}}{M}<\infty$?

Comment: I don't think so. There are probably well-known examples of dense (in any of the two topologies) subspaces of infinite codimension.

Comment: Can you give me a  counterexample ?

Comment: Hum, take $X := C([0,1],\mathbb{C})$. Take $Ev$ to be the set of evaluation maps (i.e. the maps of the form $f\mapsto f(x)$ and $M$ to be the subspace spanned by $Ev$. I think $M$ is weak-star dense and however of infinite codimension. I'll think about it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments,
$$\dim\frac{X^*}{\overline{M}^{w^*}}\le\dim\frac{X^*}{\overline{M}}\le\dim\frac{X^*}{M}$$

However equality does not hold in general.

> **Theorem (Goldstine)** :
> Let $X$ be a Banach space and $j:X\to X^{**}$ the canonical, isometric embedding. Then $j(\text{ball}(X))$ is weak-star dense in $\text{ball}(X^{**})$.

So, for example, if $M$ is a non-reflexive, Banach space (like $\ell^1$ for example) then take $X=M^*$. We have $M\cong j(M)$ and $M$ is norm-closed in $X^*$ and $M$ is weak-star dense in $X^*$. So $\frac{X^*}{\overline{M}^{w^*}}=0$. On the other hand, $\frac{X^*}{\overline{M}}=\frac{X^*}{M}$ and these are non-zero, since $M$ is non-reflexive.